# Laravel pagination get variables

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I have a page that list apartments depending on book dates like this

```
mypage.com/finder?date-from=2011-03-04&date-to=2011-03-12
```

Everything is right, I am getting the date-from and date-get from the url and searching the database with those values. The problem is when I paginate and I click to go to another page the url changes to.

```
mypage.com/finder?page=9
```

and get an error Value must be provided

The correct url must be

```
mypage.com/finder?date-from=2011-03-04&date-to=2011-03-12&page=9
```

I am using paginate at the controller and $searchResult->links(); to generate the links

What can I do pass the date values from page to page so the pagination works?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to tack on existing query string data, use this:

```php
$searchResult->appends(array(
    'date-from' => Input::get('date-from'),
    'date-to'   => Input::get('date-to'),
));
```

Read the docs: [**Appending To Pagination Links**](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links).

---

You can shorten that a little:

```php
$searchResult->appends( Input::only('data-from', 'date-to') );
```

which ends up being the same thing.

Comment: I think a better approach would be - Laravel first check for existing query string and if present, append to it else start from ?page=n. The issue with the current approach is when you click on the paging link again then your previous sorting variables are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using the 'appends' feature. There are examples in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/pagination